# Passing environment variables as parameters in python script while deploying Cloud functions

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I wanted to deploy a cloud function with python script having some parameters, by using CLI. And i want to use environment variables as parameters to my script

*main.py*

```
from sub import txn as cust 
def func(): 
  sub.cust()
```

*main.py* importing *sub.py*. *sub.py* ingesting rows to bq table and I need to pass table name, dataset and project a parameters in *sub.py* file.

*sub.py*

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

some stuff(generating random data and loading into BQ table)

dataset_ref = client.dataset(os.environ['DATASET'], os.environ['PROJECT'])
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(os.environ['TABLE'])
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
```

*env variables:*

```
DATASET='database'
PROJECT='project'
TABLE ='table'
```

And I have followed the google documentation here [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#functions-deploy-command-python) but could not able to deploy it successfully by specifying command line arguments

```
gcloud functions deploy func --runtime python37 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --region asia-northeast1 --set-env-vars DATASET=dataset,TABLE=table,PROJECT=project
```

My folder structure follows

`.env.yaml
cloubbuild.yaml
requirements
main.py
sub.py`

I'm getting this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3,
>   message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: File
>   main.py is expected to contain a function named func

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You say you couldn't deploy successfully, what error are you getting?

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: File main.py is expected to contain a function named func

Comment: but I feel, I am doing wrong in importing even variables.

Comment: Does your `main.py` file have a function named `func`? Please as much of the file as you can in the question.

Comment: sorry for that. func is my main function in main.py

Comment: `from sub import txn as cust

def func():
    sub.cust()`

This is my main.py contains

Comment: main.py importing sub.py.

sub.py ingesting rows to bq table and I need to pass table name, dataset and project a parameters in sub.py file.

Comment: Hello, how are you hadling the calls in your main? If you are using http triggered functions your main should include `def func(request):` and a return at least. I suggest you to follow the sample code from the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http) so you can handle the request and work your code from that example.

Comment: I am handling every call in main but the problem is, 
I was not exported env variables and as it could not able to retrieve the key, returning None. After exporting local env variables it worked for me.
Thanks for everyone for your efforts.